# Analogy of IntelliJ IDEA for C++ development on Windows

Tags: windows, c++, ide, netbeans, intellij

I'm going to start developing some C++ projects using at least C++11 standard. I have tried Code::Blocks and Netbeans 8.2 IDE. I prefer Netbeans 8.2 but I've got some warnings in the IDE when using C++11 syntaxes whereas the code still compiled, run and produced correct result.

I'm a big fan of IntelliJ IDEA. The dark theme of IntelliJ also one of my preferences. This is also one of my dislike for Code::Blocks and Netbeans 8.2. Is there an analogy of IntelliJ IDEA, but for C++ development? I know CLion but I can't afford to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright looks like no one can answer this question. Eventually I installed Dracular LAF Dark theme for my Netbeans 8.2 IDE. Fortunately, all warnings due to C++11 syntaxes in my code disappeared. The GUI makes me feel I have IntelliJ IDEA for C++.
[image]